# Tesseract not recognizing anything after image processing

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

This is the image before I processed it:

[image: original]

After processing, it looks like that:

[image: modified]

I think that the second one is great, but it looks like I am very wrong. When I used tesseract on original image, it recognized *some* of the text. But when I do it on the second one (the black and white one) it does not recognize anything at all! Why is that? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I've tested a little with your images. I think the main problem is the poor image quality. Try images in higher resolution, that could work a lot better.
2. I assume you only want the item names? If yes, then delete the "Buy Now for:" and the coins + the according numbers also (just paint them black like the rest), that made it better for me!
3. Also play around with the different settings of Tesseract I had the best results with psm 1 and 6 I think.

Conclusion: Higher image quality (resolution) should work the best!